# Recursive request with scrapy does not yield expected result

Tags: scrapy

I have the following code for reddit spider. When i run the code it goes through the first page and retrieves the links fine, but at the end it should make GET request to move to the next page with the following line but instead it goes through the initial response once again and fails due to exception: `DEBUG: Filtered duplicate request:`

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy
from reddit.items import RedditItem
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor
from scrapy.http import Request
import re
import HTMLParser

class RedditSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "reddit"
    allowed_domains = ["reddit.com"]
    start_urls = (
        'http://www.reddit.com/r/progresspics',
    )

    # rules = (
    #     Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=('/(\?)(count)(=\d+)(.*)' )), callback='parse', follow= True),
    # )



    def parse(self, response):
        sel = Selector(response)
        #entries = sel.Selector.xpath('//div[@class="entry upvoted"]').extract()
        entries = sel.css('.entry')
        item = RedditItem()
        for entry in entries:
            next_button = re.search("(\?)(count)(=\d+.*?[\"])",response.body)
            print next_button.group(0)
            print entry.css('.title::text').extract()
            #print entry.css('.title').xpath('.//a/@href').extract()
            image_url = entry.css('.title').xpath('.//a/@href')[0].extract()
            print(image_url)
            item['title'] = entry.css('.title::text').extract()
            item['link'] = image_url
            item['desc'] = entry.css('.title::text').extract()
            # item['image_urls'] = image_url
            # item['image'] = entry.css('.title').xpath('.//a/@href')[0].extract()
            yield item
        nextbutton='http://www.reddit.com/r/progresspics/'+next_button.group(0).replace('\"','')
        nextbutton=HTMLParser.HTMLParser().unescape(nextbutton)
        #http://www.reddit.com/r/progresspics/?count=25&amp;after=t3_2bv9c4
        #nextbutton = "http://www.reddit.com/r/progresspics/?amp=&count=50&after=t3_2brip7"
        print nextbutton
        nextrequest = Request(nextbutton, callback=self.parse)
        #yield Request(nextbutton, callback=self.parse)
        yield nextrequest
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `dont_filter=False` to your `Request`.

See http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#scrapy.http.Request for more info.

Try using this instead to check if there is a next page:

```
next = sel.xpath('//a[@rel="nofollow next"]/@href').extract()
if next:
    yield Request(url=next[0], callback=self.parse)
```

Comment: Did try that already. If i add dont_filter, it loops indefinitely the initial response.

Comment: I think it's because your regex is getting the prev button's link instead of the next one. I've edited my answer with a better way to extract the next page's link.

Comment: Yes that did it :). I needed to modify parse to "self.parse". I would edit it for others to get the correct answer. Thanks.